# Vanilla Javascript using function on Arrays with multiple values per element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

I want to use the following (creating a gallery card with information being provided through array for initial and a form for adding additional) I've been able to get the following function to work on information being added through the form but have not been able to get the function to work on the array I have.

```
function galleryAddItems(image, title){
    const galleryElement = galleryTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__image").src = image;
    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__text").textContent = title;

    galleryContainer.prepend(galleryElement);

}
```

on the array I have

```
const initialCards = [
    {
        name: "The End Place",
        link: "images/cliffside__Katie-Rodriguez.jpg"
    },
    {
        name: "Turn That Leaf Over",
        link: "images/leaf__chuttersnap.jpg"
    },
    ...

];
```

Currently have a second function set as

```
initialCards.forEach(function(thingy){
    const galleryElement = galleryTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__image").src = thingy.link;
    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__text").textContent = thingy.name;

    galleryContainer.append(galleryElement);

});
```

For this specific instance and want to avoid duplicating the code to make this work.

I've previously had galleryAddItems include .value in the function as it's needed in a different place but added that when it's being called with the hopes of it working here.
I've tried

`initialCards.forEach(galleryAddItems(link, name))`
and tried things like initialCards.link/.name
initialCardsLink/initialCardsName
If I don't put in parameters I'm not getting the image URL working and index is placed where I'm looking to have the name/title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way without changing your `galleryAddItems()` function would be:

```
initialCards.forEach(thingy => galleryAddItems(thingy.link, thingy.name));
```

Personally, I would probably think about changing the first function to something like:

```
function galleryAddItems(image) {
    const galleryElement = galleryTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__image").src = image.link;
    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__text").textContent = image.name;

    galleryContainer.prepend(galleryElement);

}
```

so that you could simply do:

```
initialCards.forEach(galleryAddItems);
```

Comment: I really appreciate you mentioning a couple of different ways to go about this. I'm just starting to learn javascript and this has helped me understand more of how the functions are being called in both of the notations, and I really appreciate it.

I'm also submitting form values into this function too and I don't think I would be able to use the other notation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to the `forEach` function, currently, you're passing the return value of `galleryAddItems` since you're calling it.

I would suggest refactoring your code so that `galleryAddItems` takes a card as a parameter and then call it for each card using `forEach`.

```
function galleryAddItems(card){
    const galleryElement = galleryTemplate.cloneNode(true);

    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__image").src = card.link;
    galleryElement.querySelector(".gallery__text").textContent = card.name;

    galleryContainer.prepend(galleryElement);

}

// Call galleryAddItems for each card
initialCards.forEach(galleryAddItems)
```

Comment: How would I input form values into this? As that's also what I'm looking to do with the function